# how to delete multiple delete in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Doubt:

Here I have mentioned Html and output Image.

If I click select all option (checkbox) it will select all image but my doubt was how to delete all images once I click delete button.

**Html**

```
{% for j in img %}
    <h4>
        Select All
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);" />
    </h4>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" action=" ">Delete</button>
    <div class="col">
        {% if i.placename == j.gallery_place %}
            <div class="show-image">
                <img src="{{j.gallery_image.url}}" style="height:130px; width:130px;" />

                <tag class="one" style="margin:8%">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="{{j.id}}" />
                </tag>

            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**image**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra5Ns.png)

Comment: You could add all the ids into for example a `POST` request, and then let the server delete these (for example in bulk).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actullay im new to django so i dono where to add it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) in Django and process them as follows. You need to create a form with the checkboxes first:

```
# forms.py
class CheckboxesForm(forms.Form):
    checkboxes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        MyModel.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Then you need to write your own FormView and override the form_valid() method to perform the deletion of the selected objects. If you want to define objects for which you have checkboxes, you can override the get_form() method.

```
# views.py
class MyListView(ListView):
    """
    View displaying a list of objects, you will redirect here after successfully deleting the objects you want
    """
    model = MyModel


class MyView(FormView):
    """
    Class based view taking care of rendering the form and processing it after posting. Finally, redirects you to your list view defined above.
    """
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['objects'] = MyModel.objects.all() # Customize this queryset to your liking
        return context

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['checkboxes'].queryset = 
            MyModel.objects.all() # Customize this queryset to determine for which objects you want to display checkboxes
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        qs = myModel.objects.filter(
            pk__in=list(map(int, self.request.POST.getlist('checkboxes'))))
        qs.delete()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('someurl'))
```

Your template will look like this (adapted from what you posted)

```
# template.html
{% for j in objects %}
    <h4>
        Select All
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);" />
    </h4>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" action=" ">Delete</button>
    <div class="col">
        {% if i.placename == j.gallery_place %}
            <div class="show-image">
                <img src="{{j.gallery_image.url}}" style="height:130px; 
width:130px;" />

            <tag class="one" style="margin:8%">
                <div class="form-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="{{ j.pk }}">
            </tag>

        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, hook up the urls.

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from.views import MyView, MyListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^listdelete/$', MyView.as_view(), name="delete-list"),
    url(r'^mylist/$, MyListView.as_view(), name="someurl"),
]
```

Comment: what i want to pass in urls.py. and we are not passing url in action 
 in delete button. @brunostuyts

Comment: I added the url config as well and added some more code for completeness. You may want to read up on Django [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/)